# Is there any framework like live helper chat in Python?

Tags: python, php, chat

Looking for only an open-source framework having ADMIN panel with modern UI and automated replies.

Found [chatterbot](https://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/) but it doesn't have all the features of [live helper chat](http://livehelperchat.com/) like Admin Panel which is in PHP.

Asked on their [Github page](https://github.com/LiveHelperChat/livehelperchat/issues/1569) too and in [slant.co](https://www.slant.co/improve/topics/24454/%7Ealternate-for-livehelperchat).

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details. So: What features do you need? How much are you willing to spend when it comes to paid solutions? Would e.g. Telegram bot support be acceptable instead of WA, or is WA a must – and what should that bot do?

Comment: almost same features; only open-source; telegram support great; will extend to WhatsApp if need

Comment: Please explicitly list those "same features" in your question. There might be folks using exactly what you're after, but never took a look at what you've linked – so they might simply skip your question (you can't expect them following several links just to find out what you need ;) So can you please **[edit]** your question accordingly? Thanks!

Comment: I do not use either WhatsApp or Telegram, so I do not know their features. That does ***not*** mean that I might not be able to recommend you some software - if you tell us what features it should have

Answer (score 0):

[Chatwoot](https://www.chatwoot.com/) is an [open-source](https://github.com/chatwoot/chatwoot) customer support solution written in Ruby (better than PHP) that helps companies engage their customers on their website, Facebook page, Twitter, Whatsapp, SMS, email, etc. It is an open-source alternative to Intercom, Drift, Freshchat, etc.

Comment: I don’t think it’s Python based as the OP requested.

Comment: I can read between the lines that the OP is fine with non-python solutions, too ;-)

Comment: @np8 From the first line . Actually, I looked in Python, but Ruby is ok and I'm gonna port it.